# Hamachi client status on webpage

Tags: php, ajax, html, web-applications, hamachi

Is there a way to get hamachi connection statuses on a webpage? I found this link:

- http://my.hamachi.cc/status/text.php?5.x.x.x

This should give a text-based status of the client with the given ip.

But it does not work. I get redirected.

I would like a status I can show using ajax, php and/or html5. No third party applications like flash or java.

Answer (score 0):

this is client side solution using jQuery:

```
$.get("http://my.hamachi.cc/status/text.php?5.x.x.x", function(data) {
 $('resultDiv').append( data ); 
});
```

Comment: Indeed this is the way to get the information to my already loaded webpage, but it is no answer to my question. I need to get the information. How I process the information is not the issue. I just added the last sentence so I wont get a flash plugin suggestion.